# Does an insert block a select? When it does not?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, acid

Consider the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE status = 'submitted' (or count (*) instead of *)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (description, id, status) VALUES ('task', '1234', 'finished')
```

Assume that these queries are executed by different transactions. Are these conflicting? Should one block the other? The select will not yield different results depending on if the insert is done before or after the select is done. But on the other hand the same column is taken into account in both cases. So should one block the other?

Comment: Is there an index on the `status` column? I think that might make a difference.

Comment: With MySQL this depends on the storage engine.

Comment: @Barmar:Actually that is my question.I want to understand how this would work with and without index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:Isn't this defined in transaction theory somehow?I know that only InnoDB has transactions